# getting distance in miles from current position

Tags: react-native

I have been struggling with this issue for a while. I want to calculate the distance in miles from current location to destination in both android and iPhone. I tried to calculate the longitude and latitude of the user current location and then put the longitude and latitude of the destination in my json file and tried to calculate the distance, but that did not work because longitude and latitude of the users current location was timing out on android. Does anyone has any example to get the distance in miles using any method in react native. I need to calculate the distance and put that in my listview. Below is what I already tried and Current longitude and Latitude position times out on android phone. I tried different workaround, but none of them works:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class GeolocationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000000000, maximumAge: Infinity },
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GeolocationExample;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You may try using [this](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib)

Comment: I already tried this one, but the issue with this is it times out in android phone. I put my code above. On android phone, the longitude and latitude always times out. I tried different ways so that it doesn't time out, but on pixel android phone, it always times out.